# How to Sum from create column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| kode | debit | kredit | status |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
|    1 |  5000 |      0 | d      |
|  221 |     0 |   5000 | k      |
|  543 |  1000 |      0 | d      |
|    1 |     0 |   1000 | d      |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
```

and that's my query before

```
SELECT kode, SUM(debit),
SUM(kredit),
CASE WHEN Status = 'd' THEN SUM(debit) - SUM(kredit)
ELSE 0
END AS SUMD,
CASE WHEN Status = 'k' THEN SUM(kredit) - SUM(debit)
ELSE 0
END AS SUMK
FROM table1
GROUP BY kode
```

But i want expectation the result like this

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
| kode | debit | kredit | status | SUMD | SUMK | TotalD | TotalK |
+------+-------+--------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |  5000 |      0 | d      | 4000 |    0 |   5000 |   5000 |
| 0221 |     0 |   5000 | k      |    0 | 5000 |   5000 |   5000 |
|  543 |  1000 |      0 | d      | 1000 |    0 |   5000 |   5000 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
```

How to SUM from column SUMD as TotalD and SUMK as TotalK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below way -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bba910e1d6e9bbcf58650f79f3a05198)**

```
with cte as
(
SELECT kode, SUM(debit),
SUM(kredit),
sum(CASE WHEN Status = 'd' THEN debit - kredit else 0 end) SUMD,
sum(CASE WHEN Status = 'k' THEN kredit - debit else 0 end) SUMK
FROM t
GROUP BY kode
)

select *,(select sum(SUMD) from cte) as totalD,(select sum(SUMK) from cte) as totalK
from cte
```

OUTPUT:

```
kode    SUM(debit)  SUM(kredit) SUMD    SUMK    totalD  totalK
1       5000        1000        4000    0       5000    5000
221      0          5000         0      5000    5000    5000
543     1000         0          1000    0       5000    5000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sum one by one and sum gross in code,you must invoke three time search in mysql